# Datos duplicados en consulta sql

Tags: oracle

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][[image: Mi consulta me arroja valores duplicados][1]]

llevo tiempo con este error, no me deja solucionar los casos que me plantean en la universidad

Comment: Trata de Explicar en texto, as imágenes no son tan claras, para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: se repiten los datos en nombre_emp

Comment: Recuerda que esto es una comunidad, no lo digo de mala manera, solo que si alguien llega con el mismo problema no sabrá porque solo ve imágenes, no se si me explico, trata de colocar tu problema y colocar código para así en futuro sirva

Comment: Para ayudarte, coloca antes del SELECT, un DISTINCT que quede SELECT DISTINCT y luego tu consulta, me avisas si te sirve.

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo leer https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask